# Java 11 JShell inside Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jshell, java-11

I have Java 11 JDK and IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4 (64-bit). When I was using Java 10.0.2, the JShell console in IntelliJ IDEA worked fine. Now that I've upgraded to Java 11, the JShell console has stopped working. Nothing at all happens when I click on the Run button or when I hit Ctrl+Enter (see screenshot).

My projects compile and run just fine using Java 11 - it's only the JShell console that doesn't work. (Also, JShell works fine from the Command Prompt, it's only inside IDEA that it doesn't work.) I can reproduce this issue on two machines, one at home running IDEA Community Edition 2018.2.4 and the other at work running Ultimate 2018.2.3.

Is there some configuration I need to do in order to fix this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: looks like `--add-modules java.xml.bind` could be the issue there. Since the module no more exists in the JDK.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This seems like a bug registered with ***JetBrains  - [IDEA-197466](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197466)*** (reported on version *2018.3*)

The reason mostly as it looks like is because of the `--add-modules java.xml.bind` there.

Since the module [`java.xml.bind` no more exists in the JDK/11](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320).

***Edit***: As [verified by OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680237/java-11-jshell-inside-intellij-idea/52681052?noredirect=1#comment93732017_52681052), this has been resolved in 2018.3 version of IntelliJ.

Comment: I've just tried it using the newly released IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 and can confirm it looks like it's been fixed. Thanks.