# java.xml.bind no more exists in the JDK/11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jshell

I'm new here and I do apologize in advance if I do here something wrong.

I tried to use JShell in IntelliJ 2018.2.5 with Java 11.0.1 but it doesn't work. Everything work just fine in command prompt and basically my problem is exactly the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52680237/java-11-jshell-inside-intellij-idea?answertab=active#tab-top). I found @nullpointer post that says it's JetBrains - IDEA-197466 bug which means that the module java.xml.bind no more exists in the JDK/11.

Is there anything I can do about it? Can I add that module somehow?